# Why doesn't my Logitech K400 keyboard/mouse always respond in raspbmc?

Tags: raspbmc, keyboard

I have a Logitech K400 wireless keyboard/mouse that I use with my Raspberry Pi (the new 512MB model).  I have Raspbmc installed.  I'd say about 50% of the time when I boot the device, the keyboard and mousepad do not do anything.

I can still use the web interface though and I can still SSH into the device.  It is definitely not hanging.

Comment: I hate to state the obvious, but how far are your keyboard/mouse from the Pi? Make sure that you're in range and that there's a clear signal (no physical blocking the infrared, etc.)

Comment: Power issue? How is the keyboard/mouse receiver powered?

Comment: Good comments, I should have addressed both of these.  I'm literally standing right on top of the unit when I test this.  When the keyboard works, it works from across the room (at least 20 feet).  It's RF, not infrared.  I thought it might be a power issue too.  The receiver is plugged directly into the Pi.  The K400 is a pretty popular keyboard for the Pi, and I haven't seen any reports of frequent issues.  I'm using a 1A 5V power adapter.  I measured 4.98V across the test points on the board.  I'm not saying that it can't be a power issue, but my first guess is some Linux config thing.

Comment: I have the same keyboard and I don't even get close to 50%. It works only very sporadically since the newest Raspbmc RC. The previous one accepted the keyboard just fine. I did find the following [page](http://elinux.org/RPi_VerifiedPeripherals#Problem_USB_Keyboards) which indicates other people have reported difficulties as well.

Comment: @Derecho is there a way to get a previous release and force it?  I'm also a little upset that the newest release doesn't support the HTTP API so the "Official XBMC Remote" for android doesn't work...

Comment: @Luke The release that did work with the keyboard was RC4, but it seems the raspbmc website only hosts the latest installer and not historical ones. You may be able to find it somewhere else, but I haven't really considered downgrading so I can't help you here.

Comment: @Derecho Check my answer, it's a kernel issue.  See if the fix works for you.

Comment: I have carefully checked the power consumption and the wireless USB makes no change to the power supply output voltage. When it works the voltages are the same value as when it fails to start. Putting new or old batteries in the keyboard does impact the range but if you can read the screen from where you use the keyboard, you are within the working envelope.
This looks to be a software issue or a problem with weird responses from the USB interface.

Comment: Same problem. Logitech K400 plus RPi and xbmc with the keyboard/pad unresponsive on power-up. A reboot usually restores the keyboard/pad interface. Interestingly, the reboot comes from a control-alt-del from the Logitech keyboard that is otherwise not working!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this thread](http://forum.stmlabs.com/showthread.php?tid=4008&highlight=k400), it is a kernel issue.  There is some general discussion on how to resolve the issue.  The poster of that thread says that in the end editing `/etc/rc.local` to include the following worked for him:

```
sleep 2
rmmod hid-logitech-dj
sleep 3
modprobe hid-logitech-dj
exit 0
```

I have tried the same and have not had any additional problems as of yet.

Answer (score -1):

Now it works correctly.

To change the layout to French:

```
root@raspberrypi:~# echo "setxkbmap fr" > ~/.xsessionrc
```

To prevent the keyboard from freezing at boot, add the following to /etc/rc.local:

```
# Configure keyboard by John
sleep 2
rmmod hid-logitech-dj
sleep 3
modprobe hid-logitech-dj
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you're saying here?  It looks like you are saying the exact same thing as my answer here.  I'm not sure what the purpose of changing the layout to French is.  Are you in France?  Is your keyboard French?